# Kentico 10 Macro List of PageType

Tags: asp.net, macros, content-management-system, kentico

I am looking for a solution to display the list of pages corresponding to a defined pagetype. I have the solution below in ASCX but I am looking for the correspondence in macro for Kentico 10.

This macro will be used in a multiple choice field in a type page.

`DocumentHelper.GetDocuments("MyPageType").OnCurrentSite().OrderByAscending("MyField");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a macro like so:

```
Documents["/%"].Children.WithAllData.Where("ClassName == 'MyPageType'").OrderBy("MyField").ApplyTransformation ("Your.Custom.RowTransformation", "<div class='content-before'>", "</div>");
```

The key is using the `Documents` object

You can also try this call:

```
Documents.WithAllData.Where("NodeAliasPath LIKE '/%' AND ClassName = 'cms.menuitem'").OrderBy("DocumentName").ApplyTransformation ("Your.Custom.RowTransformation", "<div class='content-before'>", "</div>");
```

Comment: This macro return null in my case.

Comment: Test and tweak it in the macro console. You can find it in the System app.

Comment: Check the updated answer @DavidG.  Both work in my case and return a collection of pages.